# Assigning multiple public subnet to route table using for each

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, terraform, public

I have multiple subnets created with for each that I am trying to get associated with a route table. Below is the code I have, error, and what I have tried.

```
locals {
  az_names    = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names
  pub_sub_ids = aws_subnet.public.*.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "main" {
  for_each       = var.public_sub_cidr
  subnet_id      = local.pub_sub_ids[each.key]
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.main.id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each                = { for index, az_name in local.az_names : index => az_name }
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, each.key + 1)
  availability_zone       = local.az_names[each.key]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_tags}-PubSubnet"
  }
}

Error: Unsupported attribute

  on vpc.tf line 3, in locals:
   3:   pub_sub_ids = aws_subnet.public.*.id

This object does not have an attribute named "id".
```

I believe this should be working. Any advice on this error and getting these public subnets to attach to the route table would be helpful.

**UPDATE**
I made some changes and removed the local variable 'pub_sub_ids' and also changed 'aws_route_table_association" "main" to

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "main" {
  for_each       = var.public_sub_cidr
  subnet_id      = each.key
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.main.id
}
```

Now I am getting an error

```
Error: Error creating route table association: InvalidSubnetID.NotFound: The `subnet ID '' does not exist`
```

It says the subnet does not exist even though I see it in the Console. Any advice would be appreciated in associating these public subnets to the route table.

Comment: Hi. Just a follow up. I'm curious. Did my answer with the subnets worked? If not, I wonder what was the issue?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. Your answer did work. I appreciate it. I also did figure out how to implement with for_each instead of count. What I ended up doing is setting for_each = aws_subnet.public and subnet_id = each.value.id and got it working. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`subnet_id` in `aws_route_table_association` should be subnet id, not subnet CIDR.

Since `aws_route_table` is not given, I made my own to **verify** the setup.  Thus you could do the following:

```
resource "aws_route_table_association" "main" {
   count          =  length(aws_subnet.public)
   subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public[count.index].id
   route_table_id = aws_route_table.main.id
}
```

And below is the full code I used for **verification**:

```
provider "aws" {
 # your data
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "azs" {
  state = "available"
}

locals {
  az_names = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names
}

variable "vpc_cidr" {
  default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each                = {for index, az_name in local.az_names: index => az_name}
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, each.key + 1)
  availability_zone       = local.az_names[each.key]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "main" {

 vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
  
 route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }    
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "main" {
   count          =  length(aws_subnet.public)
   subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public[count.index].id
   route_table_id = aws_route_table.main.id
}
```